# Connection Timeout Error while reading the table having more than 100 columns in Mosaic Decisions

Tags: mosaic-decisions

I am reading a table via **snowflake reader node having less number of columns/attributes(around 50-80)**,the table is getting read on the Mosaic decisions Canvas. But when the attributes of table increases **(approx 385 columns)**,Mosaic reader node fails. As a workaround I tried using the *where clause with 1=2*,in that case it is pulling the structure of the Table. But when I am trying to read the records even by applying the limit (only 10 records) to the query, it is throwing connection timeout Error.

Comment: Please provide a clear question besides the description of your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even I faced similar issue while reading (approx. 300 columns) table and I managed it with the help of **input parameters** available in Mosaic. In your case you will have to change the copy field variable to `1=1` used in the query at run time.

Below steps can be referred to achieve this -

1. Create a parameter (e.g. `copy_variable`) that will contain the default value `2` for the copy field variable
2. In reader node, write the SQL with `1 = $(copy_variable)` So while validating, it’s same as `1=2` condition and it should validate fine.
3. Once validated and schema is generated, update the default value of `$(copy_variable)` to `1` so that while running, you will still get all records.